# Cannot Execute a Release Build with MsBuild

Tags: msbuild

When I try to initiate a release configuration command line statement with MSBuild, the build executes in release mode.

**The command line executed is:**

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /t:rebuild /tv:14.0 /clp:ErrorsOnlyl /p:Platform=x86 /p:PublishToPath="c:\Publish" /p:Version=8.10.78 /p:Configuration=Release /p:IntermediateOutputPath="C:\Work" /m "C:\Repos\Solution.sln"

**The beginning of the MSBuild output reads, which confirms that the debug configuration is selected regardless:**

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/13/2022 7:19:58 PM.
1>Project "C:\Repos\Solution.sln" on node 1 (rebuild target(s)).
1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
Building solution configuration "Debug|x86".
ValidateProjects:
The project "Installer" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Debug|x86".

The solution configuration is as follows:

[Solution Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVxG3.png)

**Any ideas as to why the solution is not being built in release configuration mode?**

Comment: Can you verify that there is a 'Release' configuration in the solution? Open the solution in Visual Studio and from the Build menu choose 'Configuration Manager...'. The 'Active solution Configuration' dropdown will contain all the configurations that are defined in the solution. If there is no 'Release' (because it was removed or renamed) that will be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I added the Solution Configuration above which shows all projects are in Release configuration mode,